# What is special about unreal engine that a lot of AAA quality games are created using it?

Tags: game-development

I have seen that many AAA quality games are made using unreal engine. Why many big game development companies prefer unreal engine much more than other game engines?

Comment: They don’t always. Some use Unity, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Unreal Engine framework is setup for large scale games and multiplayer without the need for downloading third party assets or enabling plugins.
2. Unreal engines source code is public and that allows developers to edit the engines code whenever and how ever they want so they can fix bugs themselves instead of waiting for the next version of the engine with their fingers crossed that the bug will be fixed. This also allows them to tweak and optimise the engine.
3. Unreal blueprint system allows artists with minimal programming experience to work on the game directly in the engine a lot more.
4. Unreal engines licensing and royalties is much more suitable and lucrative for a company that has multiple staff.
5. Unreal is known for being a step ahead of other engines when it comes to graphics.